# WooCommerce - Fetch specific product category in page template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I would like to fetch WooCommerce product on the basis of product category on my page template.

Lets say I have a category **`mattress`**. I want to fetch all the products related to that **`mattress`** category.

Here is my code:

```
  <?php 

        // Start the Loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                // Include the page content template.
                get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                    comments_template();
                }
            endwhile;
        ?>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a "write my code please" site.  You need to explain your specific problem.  If someone's answer below "doesn't work", you have to be SPECIFIC about what doesn't work.  Further, you say "let's say I have a category mattress" - well, DO YOU? And do you have products in that category? If not, then NONE of the answers will appear to work.  Both answers below are correct, so if it "doesn't work", the problem is likely in how you've implemented it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WooCommerce Custom Loop to get all product from one specific category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330666/woocommerce-custom-loop-to-get-all-product-from-one-specific-category)

Answer (score 2):

**— — ( Update 2 of the August 8th ) — —**

Finally a good alternative is to use [**`has_term();`** wordpress function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) to filter all products of some category in an **`if`** statement. If you have multiple categories you can embed them in an array using also **`has_term();`** function.

> As I have said before below on a comment, I think that your problem is here:
>
> ```
> // Include the page content template.
> get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
> ```

So I will replace it with some custom code to show you that the condition is working fine:

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Start the Loop
    If($loop->have_posts()){
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

            // Here it is your product category
            if ( has_term( 'mattress', 'product_cat', $loop->post ); ) {

                // from here I display products thumbnails and name

                echo '<div class="woocommerce-product" style="padding:5px; float:left;">';

                if (has_post_thumbnail( $product_id )) {
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog');
                } else {
                    echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; 
                }
                echo '<div class="product-name">' . $loop->post->post_name . '</div>';
                echo '</div>';

            }

        endwhile;
    }
// If needed
wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

It also works without condition: `has_term( 'mattress', 'product_cat', $loop->post );` replacing **`$args`** array by this one:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // you can set here number of post per page
    'tax_query'      => array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'mattress '
     ) )
);
```

**This code is tested and fully functional** *and it goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme*.

Reference:

- [Display different custom fields for different categories in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759654/display-different-custom-fields-for-different-categories-in-woocommerce/38765831#38765831)
- [WordPress Function Reference - has_term()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)

---

***— — ( Update 1 - july 9th ) — —***

Or you can also use `has_category();` function to filter in an **`if`** statement this way:

```
<?php 

    global $post;

    // Start the Loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        if ( has_category( 'mattress', $post ); ) {

            // Include the page content template.
            get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                comments_template();
            }
        }

    endwhile;
?>
```

---

You could try this:

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // you can set here number of post per page
        'tax_query'      => array( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'mattress '
         ) )
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    If($loop->have_posts()){
        while($loop->have_posts()) {
            $loop->the_post();

            // Include the page content template.
            get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );


            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                comments_template();
            }
        }
    }
    // If needed
    wp_reset_query();
    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Comment: thanx for you reply .... I am getting reviews on my page but I want to show product related to mattress category..

Comment: @websmentor.com I think that your problem is `get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); …`. With that you aren't able to display products, but only getting description, review from product page… Look at the templates included with woocommerce: [Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) … the solution is in another combination… My code is Ok … look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38278017/3730754

Answer (score 1):

Below code should work.

```
<?php

$query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5&post_type=product&product_cat=mattress');


If($query->have_posts()){
    while($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();

        // Your Code


    }
}

wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Comment: It's not working...i Have created page template on that I am trying to call

Comment: Is it possible for you to paste the code here so that i can help you

Answer (score 1):

```
     <ul>

          <?php
               $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
               $orderby      = 'title';  
               $show_count   = 0;
               $pad_counts   = 0;
               $hierarchical = 1;  
               $title        = '';  
               $empty        = 0;

          $args = array(
              'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
              'orderby'      => $orderby,
              'show_count'   => $show_count,
              'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
              'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
              'title_li'     => $title,
              'hide_empty'   => $empty
          );

         $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
               foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
                      $category_id = $cat->term_id;?>

                      <li><a href="<?php echo   get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat');?>"><?php echo $cat->name;?></a></li>
           <?php }?>
        </ul>
```