# Display different custom fields for different categories in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to display different custom fields for different categories in WooCommerce.

I have used the following conditional statement in content-single-product.php template file:

```
      if(is_product_category('categoryname'))
    {
         // display my customized field
    }
else
{
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
}
```

But this isn't working for me.

Is there any better way to rectify this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is_product_category() will not work for you in single product templates. The correct conditions are a combination of two in this case:

```
if ( is_product() && has_term( 'categoryname', 'product_cat' ) ) {

    // display my customized field

} 
....
```

It looks like you are trying to override **`content-single-product.php`** template.

Moving **`woocommerce_single_product_summary`** hook inside your ELSE statement is not a very good idea, only if you don't want to display for **`'categoryname'` product** that 3 hooked functions:

```
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
```

Instead (of overriding templates here) you could embed your code *(on function.php file of your active child theme or theme)* in a hooked function using the more convenient of this 2 hooks:

```
//In hook 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' with priority up to 50.

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'displaying_my_customized_field', 100);
function displaying_my_customized_field( $woocommerce_template_single_title, $int ) { 
    if ( is_product() && has_term( 'categoryname', 'product_cat' ) ) {

        // echoing my customized field

    } 
};
```

OR

```
// In hook 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' with priority less than 10

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'displaying_my_customized_field', 5);
function displaying_my_customized_field( $woocommerce_template_single_title, $int ) { 
    if ( is_product() && has_term( 'categoryname', 'product_cat' ) ) {

        // echoing my customized field

    } 
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Overriding content-single-product.php worked for me. Thanks again.