# Wordpress displaying products in a category

Tags: wordpress

Hi I'm using wordpress and I'm trying to loop all products in a category, how would I do this without using the shortcodes?

Thanks Jonny

Comment: Products? What e-commerce plugin are you using? WooCommerce? FreeCart?

Comment: Oh sorry woocommerce

Comment: WooCommerce usually sets up a category page based on URL. `example.com/product-category/category-slug/` Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: So I need a php loop to check all the products in a category and echo them out.

Comment: You're doing this in the hard code?

Comment: yeah trying to do it

Comment: That's been asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330666/woocommerce-custom-loop-to-get-all-product-from-one-specific-category